# convert {{var customer.getName()}} to customer name

Tags: magento2, custom-variable

I am create SMS module and in SMS template i use custom variable such as `{{var customer.getName()}}` .

How i can convert this variable to same variable for example if user use `{{var customer.getName()}}` in SMS template when SMS was sent customer see his/here name in SMS

Answer (score 0):

I create this method

```
    private function replace($string, $customer='', $order=''){


            $str='';
            $string=explode(" ",$string);
            foreach ($string as $item){
                $new_word=$item;
                if(strpos($item,'$') !== false){
                    $word=explode(".",$item);

                    if($word[0]=='$customer')
                    {
                        $c_word="get".ucfirst($word[1]);
                       $new_word= $customer->$c_word();

                    }elseif($word[0]=='$order'){
                        $o_word="get".ucfirst($word[1]);
                        $new_word= $order->$o_word();

                    }
                }

                $str.=" ".$new_word;

            }
            return $str;
  }
```

I know this way is not a magento way but for now fixed my problem and i am   stay in waiting for better way

```
            $this->replace("hi $customer.name your id is $customer.id ",$customer,$order);
```